# Array multidimensional

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou a tentar criar um array multidimensional. Primeiro pretendia colocar todos os primeiros elementos com valor 2 então fiz:

```
l=4
x=6
TSup=[ [ 2 for i in range(l) ] for j in range(x) ]
print TSup
```

e obtive o esperado:

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Agora pretendo alterar o código de modo que o 1º valor seja a respetiva posição de uma lista Test, ou seja, queria que o 1º elemento fosse 290, o 2º 293, o 3º 291 e o 4º 294, para isso alterei da seguinte forma:

```
Test=[290,293,291,294]
l=4
x=6
for a in range(len(Test)):

    TSup=[ [ Test[a] for i in range(l) ] for j in range(x) ]

print (TSup)
```

mas não dá o esperado, dá apenas o valor para a ultima iteração, 4ª posição:

```
[[294, 294, 294, 294], [294, 294, 294, 294], [294, 294, 294, 294], [294, 294, 294, 294], [294, 294, 294, 294], [294, 294, 294, 294]]
```

e eu queria:

```
[[290, 293, 291, 294],[290, 293, 291, 294],[290, 293, 291, 294],[290, 293, 291, 294],[290, 293, 291, 294],[290, 293, 291, 294]]
```

Se alguém me conseguir ajudar, agradecia imenso!

Answer (score 1):

O operador `*` serve justamente para isso:

```
n = 6
final = [[290, 293, 291, 294]]*n
```

Comment: Como se chama essa operação? Tem algum nome? Não fazia que dava assim

Comment: Olha esse link: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-multidimensional-list

Comment: Muito bom, não conhecia

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
for a in range(len(Test)):
    Tsup = [ [Test[i] for i in range(l)] for j in range(x) ]
```

ou simplesmente assim:

```
Tsup = [ [Test[i] for i in range(l)] for j in range(x) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Temos de criar 6 listas iguais a teste dentro de uma lista 'mãe':

```
test = [290,293,291,294]
final = [[i for i in test] for i in range(6)]
print(final) # [[290, 293, 291, 294], [290, 293, 291, 294], [290, 293, 291, 294], [290, 293, 291, 294], [290, 293, 291, 294], [290, 293, 291, 294]]
```